# Need help to call functions in diffrent class

Tags: python

I am still mastering Python. and below is my code. I want to access the function  move_slide_up(): inside class PresentationFunctions and pass the Listbox_name as input but i am getting attribute not found error . any help would be helpful

```
class Rearange_files():
  def move_slide_up(list_box_name):
        name  = list_box_name 

        index =  name  .curselection()
        if not index:
            return
        for idx in index:
            if idx > 0:
                title = name  .get(idx)
                name  .delete(idx)
                name  .insert(idx-1, title)
                name  .selection_set(idx-1)
                    
        ###Move file names down in list box


class PresentationFunctions:

        list_box_filename =tk.Listbox(slide_order_window, selectmode = "multiple",height=15,width 
        list_box_filename.pack( padx=20,pady=5)

        ""Need to call   function move_slide_up(): here
```

i am seeing atrribute not found erorr

Comment: Is there a reason you're grouping functions in classes? Functions inside classes are known as methods and should take in the `self` parameter, which allows you to use data contained within the class. Your current implementation looks like you should just have `move_slide_up` as a top level function.

Comment: my knowledge is limited and till learning things in python.  Could you please show me the correct way to write the function and also if possible please provide  insights that why i  have to follow that .Which helps me alot

Comment: You don't need to use classes at all in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
class Rearange_files():
  def move_slide_up(self, list_box_name):
        name  = list_box_name
        index =  name.curselection()
        if not index:
            return
        for idx in index:
            if idx > 0:
                title = name.get(idx)
                name.delete(idx)
                name.insert(idx-1, title)
                name.selection_set(idx-1)

        ###Move file names down in list box


class PresentationFunctions:
    """
    Define slide order window
    width
    """
    list_box_filename =tk.Listbox(slide_order_window, selectmode="multiple", height=15, width=15)
    list_box_filename.pack(padx=20, pady=5)
    rearrange_file_obj = Rearange_files()
    rearrange_file_obj.move_slide_up(list_box_filename)
```

Comment: Thank you i  already tried this method but  the move function was not working . But thank you once again for the help :) this helps me for my future assignments